# ng-route click on href disappared view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

when click on href="#" on my nav-bar the view disappared!
Why???? this is my code below on link.
Thank's a lot!

http://plnkr.co/edit/bQPZOnWP6RhNecMJwI81?p=preview

```
     [1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/bQPZOnWP6RhNecMJwI81?p=preview
```

Comment: navbar is not opening for me..

Comment: ...if you resize screen you see test button when click it i open my view but when for example click title with href="#" my view disappared...why???

Answer (score 0):

can you add the below code to your nav-bar and check once
`target="_self"` `ng-href="#"`